# How do I remove get variables and filename from URL using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url, variables

I was looking into this issue but I couldn't find any solid answers for this specific purpose. Let's say I have a URL of...

http://mysite.com/stuff/index.php?search=my+search

How can I grab this URL and remove index.php?search=my+search from it so it would just be http://mysite.com/stuff/ ? Basically I just want to grab the parent URL without a filename or get variables... No matter what the URL (so I don't have to customize the function for every page I want to use it on)

So for an additional example, if it were just...

http://mysite.com/silly.php?hello=ahoy

I would just want to return the root of http://mysite.com

Can anyone give me a hand in figuring this out? I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using `lastIndexOf("/")`:

```
var url = "http://mysite.com/stuff/index.php?search=my+search";
url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
alert(url); // it will be "http://mysite.com/stuff/"
```

OR

```
var url = "http://mysite.com/silly.php?hello=ahoy";
url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
alert(url); // it will be "http://mysite.com/"
```

Comment: Thanks, I imagine I'll be using lastIndexOf constantly now.

Comment: `console.log(url)` is much, much better than alert.

Answer (score 2):

If your url is in `str`:

```
newstr = str.replace(/\/[^\/]+$/,"");
```

`newstr` now contains the path up to but excluding the last `/` in the string. To keep the final `/`, use:

```
newstr = str.replace(/\/[^\/]+$/,"/");
```

Answer (score 2):

split on "/", discard the last piece, join them back up, add trailing slash.

```
var path = location.href.split('/');
path.pop();
path = path.join("/") + "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `location.host` or `location.hostname`. But would you like to extract them from a complete string rather than from current URL?

I read the question once more and it seems you want get the string which consists of:

```js
location.protocol + "//" + location.host + location.pathname
```

right?

Comment: `location.pathname` will contain `index.php`