# How to alert URL exclude filename.php in javascript?

Tags: javascript, alert

I have tried this alert but not getting result what exactly I want

Suppose my URL = http://expense.test/admin/manageExpense.php
I want alert (http://expense.test/admin/)

```
var base_url = window.location.origin + '/' + window.location.pathname.split ('/') [1] + '/';
```

Above query getting exact result which i want but when i alert below URL it's not exactly which i want.
Suppose my url is
http://expense.test/admin/admin/admin/index.php
when i alert with above query it's getting me same alert (http://expense.test/admin/) but I want alert (http://expense.test/admin/admin/admin/) , How can i achieve this. Any Help will be appreciated
Main focus how many folders with url but i want to exclude last filename from URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer

```
var url = "http://expense.test/admin/admin/admin/index.php";
url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
alert(url);
```

Thanks to this man 
[How do I remove get variables and filename from URL using javascript/jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145118/how-do-i-remove-get-variables-and-filename-from-url-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the last part of your URL you can simply [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) it after splitting by `/`.

```js
function remove(url) {
  var splitedUrl = url.split("/");
  splitedUrl.pop();
  return splitedUrl.join('/') + '/';
}

console.log(remove("http://expense.test/admin/manageExpense.php"));
console.log(remove("http://expense.test/admin/admin/manageExpense.php"));
```